# Converting list (array values) into integers and then print out the input which the array holds as the converted integers not words

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

```
    firstsentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
    firstsentence = firstsentence.lower()
    words = firstsentence.split(' ')
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(words)
    for (i, firstsentence) in enumerate(my_list):
        if (aword == my_list): #This is where i get confused
            print(str(i+1)+ ' position')
            print (my_list)
```

So what i am try to do is ask the user for an input - "firstsentence". I will then try to split the inputted sentence into words and store them in the array (list) my_list. I am getting stuck on how to convert the seperated words into numbers (their positions in the sentence) and then printing out the input("firstsentence") as the integer version. 'aword' is what i used to try and identify if the word was repeated in the sentence. This is quite confusing and here is an example :-
"I like to do coding because I like it and i like it a lot"
There are 15 words here. Of these 15, only 10 are different. So the repeated words **MUST** be put into the same integer (even though their positions are different their actual word is the same) value in the array. The code i want to print out should look like this for the sentence above:-
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 7 8 1 2 7 9 10. I am really confused as to how to store the separated words as different values (integers) and then especially on how to store the same repeating words as one value, and then printing the whole thing out.  Thanks to those who help. Would be much appreciated :-).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is deliberately incomplete.  It's clear you're new at this, and part of being new is discovering how code works.  But you're lacking in some basic concepts of what to do with lists in python, and this should point you in the right direction.

```
firstsentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
firstsentence = firstsentence.lower()
words = firstsentence.split(' ')
my_list = []
for word in words:
    print(word in my_list) 
    # You can do something more useful than print here, right?
    # Maybe add the specific word to my_list...

for word in words:
    print(my_list.index(word))
    # This gives you the index, but you need to figure out how to output it the way you want
    # Note that indices in python start at 0 while your sample output starts
    # at 1.  So maybe do some addition somewhere in here.
```

So, what's happening here?

We're doing two passes. 
Generally, you'll get very far in programming if you can decompose a problem into discrete steps.  In this case, there are two steps to your problem - find the index of the first occurrence of each word, and then output the right indices.

In the first pass, you'll create a list of unique words, where their ordering reflects their ordering in the sentence.

In the second pass, you'll go through the original sentence and look up the place where it first occurred, and format that the way you need.

If you're really attentive, you'll realize: *you could easily do this in one pass.*  What does the second pass require?  Just that the word you're looking for be in `my_list`.  As long as you meet that requirement, you could combine the two loops.  This is a good thing to do - it may not matter when you're looking at 20 words, but what if you were looking at 20,000,000,000 words?  You'd really only want one loop.  But take small steps.  Start by figuring out how to do it with two loops, and then maybe move on to putting it all in one.

Comment: So now you know that I'm a bit of a newbie now [ :-) ] - can you simplify what you mean a bit more please? Would help a lot